# call a view function from a L1 contract in a L2 contract

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, layer-2

I'm wondering is there a way to read a view function that is deployed on L1(Ethereum) on L2(e.g. Optimism) and vice-versa

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

// pretend this is on L1
contract L1_contract {
    uint256 public a = 0 ;
    function read_a() public view  returns(uint256){
        return a;
    }
    function increament_a() public {
        a +=1 ;
    }
}
// pretend this is on L2 
contract L2_contract {
    address private l1_contract_address = 0x95aD61b0a150d79219dCF64E1E6Cc01f0B64C4cE;
    uint256 private l1_chain_id = 1 ;
    function read_a_from_l1() public view returns(uint256){

        // some code that I don't know 
        return a_on_l2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polygon used to have a data bridge where validators passed over arbitrary info, but I don't see it anymore. Unfortunately you'd need to use an oracle as if it's any other chain (or off-chain info).  I know Tellor has a flexible structure that allows contract calls to other chains, but technically any oracle structure can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I belive you can. Maybe this can help:

```
contract C1 {
    function f1() returns(uint) {
        return(10);
    }
}

contract C2 {
    function f2(address addrC1) returns(uint) {
        C1 c1 = C1(addrC1);
        return c1.f1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good use case for multichain's anycall
https://docs.multichain.org/developer-guide/how-to-integrate-cross-chain-anycall-contract